# Bind utility and templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, bind

It follows a minimal example of the `bind` function in use.
It compiles and it is pretty trivial an example indeed.

```
#include <functional>

void fn(int i) { }

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto f = std::bind(fn, x);
}
```

I would be interested in doing the same with a templated function.
It follows the example above, even though slightly modified. This one doesn't compile, but it explains exactly which is the intended behavior.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void fn(T t) { }

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto f = std::bind(fn, x);
}
```

Quite simple a question: is it possible to use `bind` utility with a templated function?

Comment: If you don't know the type of `x` when calling you need late binding. The standard `bind` does not do this, but if you find yourself in need, I made a small library that does (https://github.com/masaers/blind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the obvious solution is the code below.

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void fn(T t) { }

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    auto f = std::bind(fn<int>, x);
}
```

If you don't want to be specific about the instantiation, maybe you can add one more template level.  I'm making some tests.

**EDIT:** I spent a few hours thinking by myself, googling around and reading my printed TC++PL4Ed, as well as reading the implementation of GNU's libstdc++ source code, and I didn't figure nor did I find out how to do what you asked.

It turns out that when you made `fn` the name of a template, it could no longer be used as the name of an object.  Since `std::bind` deduces its return type from (the types of) its arguments, the use of just `fn` became invalid.  To have a callable object that qualifies as first argument to `std::bind`, you must now instantiate the template `fn`.

Comment: Yeah, the target is to be not specific about the instantiation, sorry if it didn't emerge from the question. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: @skypjack, I edited my response.  See if got any more useful.

Comment: Actually it was an XYProblem, I've reduced too much the original code, then I found from your response that this question makes no longer sense for the original problem. Anyway, it's a question and I guess you replied right to it, than you!! :-)